# Unity app changes URI scheme to https from http when built to ios

Tags: ios, http, unity-game-engine, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have a Unity project that uses the Azure Storage SDK to connect to Azure Table Storage to get data. According to this documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sandbox/gamedev/unity/azure-storage-unity) there is an issue using https and the workaround is to use http. This works fine when running the app in Unity. I get the data from the storage and if I log the scheme and look at it, it is http.

But when I build to ios the uri scheme changes to https

I have made sure that the checkbox "Allow downloads over HTTP" in player settings is checked.

What am I missing?

Comment: Which SDK and version are you using when encountering this issue ?

Comment: @AdamSmith-MSFT Unity is on version 2017.3.1f1. And I cant seem to find the version of the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage dll but the zipfile containing the SDK dlls has the version number 8.6.0